# MPDF {PAGENO} not working in codeigniter in showing page number in pdf

Tags: php, codeigniter, mpdf

I was working with a existing CodeIgniner Project and it is deals with MDPF to generate pdf file. Now, I am trying to put a page number in the top-right of the pdf page. Here is my code based on https://mpdf.github.io/paging/page-numbering.html

```
$data = [ .. some data here ..];
$sheet_summary = $this->load->view('pdf/sheet', $data, true);
$pdf2 = $this->m_pdf->load(['defaultPageNumStyle' => '1']);

$pdfFilePath_2 = "sheet-summary-".date('Ymd').".pdf";
$pdf2->mirrorMargins = 1;
$pdf2->setHeader('||{PAGENO}'); 
$pdf2->AddPage('','','','','on');

$pdf2->WriteHTML($sheet_summary);
$pdf2->Output("./uploads/".$pdfFilePath_2, "F");
```

Comment: Is this the actual code or did you modify something? I see a broken string on the line : `$pdfFilePath_2 = "sheet-summary-".date('Ymd')".pdf";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is in the `AddPage()` function, the `on` parameter must be `off` if you want to see the page number.

If you leave it `on`, the page number is invisible.

You have more info in this link, on section "Page Numbering":
http://www.halfaro.com/halfaro/mpdf/CHANGELOG.txt